# I'm not able to move any object to collection

Tags: objects, 3d-view, collections

all of my objects are in a collection called "Objects" as you can see the orange collection icon If i try to drag and drop or even use "M" key to move objects to collection it does't do any thing[image]

Comment: The orange "Objects" is not a collection, it is a collection instance, as indicated by the icon. Collections have a a white icon. What you are doing by drag and drop is parenting to an empty object

Comment: what's the solution? How do I  move it to collection? I used to work on maya I just shifted to blender so I'm kinda new

Comment: Could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/